# C++ - return different variable types

Tags: c++, templates, variables, types, return

I don't know if this is possible but maybe there are other solutions to what I want. I am trying to get settings from a settings file. They can be strings (like names), integers or booleans. Of course, they are stored as text inside the file but I will create a class for opening and returning settings, yet not as string but as what each one of them are in fact.

```
class Settings {
    public:
        Settings(string FileName);
        template <class T> T Setting(string SettingName);
}
```

The constructor would load the file, will parse the settings and store them as a  map, for example.
Now, when I call the Setting member function I want it to identify what type is the value of the requested setting (if it is numeric, a integer, if is "true" or "false" a boolean, if is alphanumeric a string) and return a value of that type. An example

```
Settings UserPreferences("Preferences.cfg");
bool AutoLogin = UserPreferences.Setting("autologin");  // return bool
string UserName = UserPreferences.Setting("username"); // return string or char*
```

I had a look over templates but it looks like I have to specify what variable I expect when creating the Settings object but that's not the point. I am happy with declaring the type of the variable to return like this:

```
bool AutoLogin = UserPreferences.Setting<bool>("autologin");
string UserName = UserPreferences.Setting<string>("username");
```

but I don't know if that is possible. What do you think?

Comment: I have such a class that works fine. So yeah, I *think* it's possible. ;)

Comment: I was very surprised it worked, given that you can't overload on return type.

Comment: @BoBTFish: But they are not overloads. They are specializations. The template parameter can't be deduced from return type, but when you give it explicitly, it's fine.

Comment: @BoBTFish Another similar example would be `std::make_shared` called with no arguments: each invocation only differs from the other ones by its return type.

Comment: @BoBTFish: By the way there actually is a case where you can overload on return type. It would allow some nice syntactic sugar here, though it might be confusing to the uninitiated.

Comment: If you happen to use one type more frequently than the rest, you could use default template arguments: template <class T=int>. Danger is forgetting to provide arguments because of this and using the default type where it doesn't need to be.

Comment: I tried but I get an error and that might be caused by the fact that I declare the class in a header then each member is placed in a CPP. I get this linking error (it's a DLL): `unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall Settings::Setting<bool>(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >)" (??$Setting@_N@Settings@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. This is very similar to the example at 14.8.1 Explicit template argument specification, paragraph 1, so I'm convinced it is legal, although I need to read it a few more times to be sure I understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible, although you have to have some guarantee that it can cast to the given type. This is seen a lot in XNA's ContentLoader (albeit a much different system). You can use this approach to simplify and abstract how things are stored an retrieved. Consider:

```
class Loader
{
private:
    vector<void*> _items;
public:
    template <typename Type>
    Type GetItem( int index ) { return (Type)(_items[ index ]); }
};
```

The idea is that as long as you can cast the internal data to the requested type reliably (more reliably than the example) than it is a perfectly legal operation. How to make that a guaranteed success is another question entirely, but you can definitely have methods whose return type is that of the their template types. Consider the following example (I used this is a college project for a resource loader):

Header.h

```
class BasicResource
{
public:
    static const int ResourceID;
    const int ID;
    BasicResource( )
        : ID( ResourceID )
    {
    }
};

class Loader
{
private:
    vector<BasicResource*> _items;
public:
    template <typename Type>
    Type GetItem( int index );
};

#include "inline.inl"
```

Inline.inl

```
template <typename Type>
Type Loader::GetItem( int index )
{
    auto item = _items[ index ];
    if( item != nullptr && item->ID == Type::ResourceID )
    {
        return (Type)_item;
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the fail case somehow
    }
}
```

Inline files allow you to seperate your logic as you normally would, but include it in the header which allows for export of template methods.

Comment: Thank, William. Your example works but I would like to have this inside a DLL. The problem is that I can't (or don't know how to) split the class between the .h (interface) and .cpp (implementation). I don't even know if it is possible. Is it?

Comment: @ali Templated code has to be in some header file (typically). So you can only move the non-templated implementations, like the constructor, in a .cpp

Comment: So, I can't move the templated function's code in the .cpp and leave a declaration in the header? Can't templated members be exported from a shared/dynamic library?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is certainly possible. I've written the following bit of complete code to prove the point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>


struct Settings
{
  typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> SettingsMap;
  template <class T> T as( const std::string& name ) const
  {
    std::istringstream is( getEntry( name ) );
    T value;
    if( is )
    {
      if( (is >> value) || (is.eof() && !is.fail()) )
      {
        return value;
      }
    }
   //Exception handling not in scope of question
   throw std::runtime_error( "..." );
};

const std::string& getEntry( const std::string& name ) const
{
  SettingsMap::const_iterator pos( settingsMap_.find( name ) );
  if( pos != settingsMap_.end() )
  {
    return pos->second;
  }
  //Not part of the scope of this answer....
  throw std::invalid_argument( "No such setting..." );
}

Settings()
{
  settingsMap_["mybool"] = "1";
  settingsMap_["myint"] = "5";
  settingsMap_["myfloat"] = "43.2";
}

SettingsMap settingsMap_;
};

int main()
{
  Settings s;
  std::cout << s.as<bool>("mybool") << " "
    << s.as<int>("myint") << " "
    << s.as<float>("myfloat");

  return 0;
}
```

I've implemented something similar to this, but I've used boost::any as my mapped type, and I've read the actual type during the first parse, therefore ensuring that the stored type is correct. I've also used boost::lexical_cast instead of native istringstream, but I've omitted that for the purpose of proving the point.